# How to cancel a process when Control+C is pressed in a shell script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, cmd, command-line-interface

I have a script that does some work. It does it in a proper way but it takes a while before it ends. Because I want to simulate that "job is running now" I added a spinner cursor animation.

I call it at the beginning of my script, then I assign the PID of that function to a variable and when everything is done, I simply kill it to stop the animation.

```
#!/bin/bash

spinner &
SPINNER_PID=$!

# a lot of stuff going on here...
# takes some time to finish

kill $SPINNER_PID &>/dev/null

printf "All done"
```

Function definition:

```
spinner() {
  local i sp n
  sp='/-\|'
  n=${#sp}
  while sleep 0.1; do
    printf "%s\b" "${sp:i++%n:1}"
  done
}
```

All works fine if I won't interrupt.

Imagine that I want to cancel my long task by calling `Control+C`. It cancels but the spinner obviously still animates since it's noting else that an infinite loop.

[image]

How I can kill it when script is cancelled manually and won't reach to `kill $SPINNER_PID &>/dev/null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a statement called `trap` that allows you to run code when `Ctrl-C` is pressed. There is a good explanation of it [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html), and [this website](https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash)
 explains how to run a function on `Ctrl-C`.

```
trap your_func INT
```